# uploading code to github

Tags: windows, linux, git

I have created a  repository named appengine-testers on github. It is a public repository. Though I easily managed to create a repository but I do not know how to store code there. Do I need to upload the code/folder ?

Comment: Some good resources: GitHub help docs (https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo). Hanselman blog: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetInvolvedInOpenSourceTodayHowToContributeAPatchToAGitHubHostedOpenSourceProjectLikeCode52.aspx

Comment: Have you tried reading the github instructions?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to do that, i'll just briefly tell the simple one.

```
git clone ssh-path-to-project
```

It creates .git folder in the project which is used for references.

```
cd project
```

copy the entire project code from any location and paste it in this folder.

Now
Add all the untracked files.

```
git add .
git commit -am <"commit message">
```

or

```
git commit -a
```

Which automatically takes the changes.Lastly

```
git push
```

It pushed the entire code to the repository

One more simple option is do

```
git init
```

in the project folder and then change the remote url in the .git folder created inside the project folder

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the repo on github, it'll give you a URL (that looks kinda like `git@github.com:yourusername/appengine-testers.git`) with push access.  From there, you just push from your local repo to that URL.

It's probably easier if you add that URL as a remote.  Typically you'd call it 'origin'.

Comment: That's a HTTPS url.  You should be able to push to it as well.  Try using it the same way i was talking about.  If it doesn't work, try going to the github repo in your browser and finding the SSH URL.  (I personally prefer using SSH, cause i'm not sure how the HTTPS auth works, and keys are easier to manage than passwords. :) )